# Goal Tracking data seems to be inaccurate?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I setup some Goal Tracking about one week ago. I had multiple goals in one set. The goal itself was the "send" button being pressed on the callback form (i did that by pushing a page view to Google Analytics every time the send button is pressed)

For each goal, i listed the first step as a required step.
So for example, the ILR Page was step 1 and set as required and the goal was `/CallbackFormFilled`

Looking at the stats a week later i'm getting some very inflated numbers especially when comparing them to my manually filled excel spreadsheet and i'm struggling to understand the cause of this behaviour.

I'm unable to attach screenshots unfortunately since my StackExchange account for this site is brand new

**My own thoughts**

My own thoughts were that maybe its because I have setup multiple goals with the same end goal URL, but I thought that was a valid setup since I want to track multiple routes so to speak.

I've disabled all other goals for now to confirm this, but I'm waiting for stats to come in as I write this.

I also wonder if the contact form I'm using in WordPress is causing a problem, but I've simply added one JavaScript line on the send button that pushes a page view so not sure if that should cause an issue. Here is a link to setting up analytics on this contact form plugin in WordPress for reference: [JavaScript action hook section](http://ideasilo.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/contact-form-7-1-10/)

Comment: Did you get stats back on this?

Comment: Yes - I did. You cant setup the same goal URL for multiple goals, otherwise you get duplicate data. I had to add some javascript to the contact form so that it appended it with additional parameters on the URL so that i could specify a different URL for each goal.

Let me know if you need further help on this.

Comment: I haven't had that issue.

You should post your comment as an answer and mark it as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't setup the same goal URL for multiple goals, otherwise you get duplicate data. I had to add some JavaScript to the contact form so that it appended it with additional parameters on the URL so that I could specify a different URL for each goal.